# Solution set of $3^{2x^2}-2.3^{{x^2}+x+6}+3^{2(x+6)}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solution set of $$3^{2x^2}-2.3^{{x^2}+x+6}+3^{2(x+6)}=0$$ is?

I tried to think of dividing something like $3^x$ or $3^{2x}$ so to make the equation like in form of quadratic but couldn't think of one. Please help.

Comment: Letting $ f ( x ) = 3 ^ x $, $ u = 2 x ^ 2 $ and $ v = 2 x + 12 $, what is the equation telling you? What property of the function $ f $ does that address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Take $a = 3^{x^2}$ and $b = 3^{x+6}$

To get
$$a^2 - 2ab + b^2 =0 $$
$$\implies (a-b)^2 = 0$$
$$\implies ?$$

Comment: Thank You IITian!

Answer (score 4):

Hint. The LHS is a square
$$3^{2x^2}-2\cdot3^{{x^2}+x+6}+3^{2(x+6)}=(3^{x^2}-3^{x+6})^2.$$

Comment: Thank You for your help!